# SQL Union All alias from first table?

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all

I have two tables

[data] - title,maker,partnum,price

[cross] - product(data.partnum),title,maker,partnum,price

What I want is listing all product via sysn number. How can I get with union all data like that with ordering ->

1. [data table] Microsoft, "some note", 9989, $20
2. [cross table] Microsoft reseller, "some note", 1045, $30
3. [cross table] Apple reseller in Microsoft :), "some note", 2233, $40
4. virtual spacer :)
5. [data table] Microsoft, "some note", 9989, $10
6. [cross table] Lenovo reseller in Microsoft..

Im trying with this

```
SELECT `title`,'Microsoft' AS `maker`,`partnum`,`price`
    FROM data as d
    WHERE sysn=%s
    GROUP BY partnum
UNION ALL
    SELECT `title`,`maker`,`partnum`,`price`
    FROM cross as c
    WHERE c.product=d.partnum
    GROUP BY `partnum`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking. Consider setting up an example schema and data in http://sqlfiddle.com.

A "virtual spacer" is going to be very messy to achieve. It's not totally impossible, just messy.

For returning rows in a particular sequence, you are going to need to add an `ORDER BY` clause.

It's not at all clear why you are including `GROUP BY` clauses. The `GROUP BY` on the first `SELECT` would effectively "collapse" example output rows 1. and 5. given the same value `9989` for `partnum`.  Absent an explanation of why you need a `GROUP BY`, I'm going to guess that what you really intended was an `ORDER BY` clause.

It's also not clear why the literal value `'Microsoft'` would need to appear in the `SELECT` list, in place of the `maker` column from the `data` table. There's nothing invalid SQL-wise with doing that. But absent an explanation, it just doesn't make much sense.

The question we should to ask... Why is this specific result needed? Is there a different result which would be easier to achieve, which would equally satisfy the requirements?

Setting aside the "virtual spacer" row, the return from a query like this seems like it satisfies most of the specification:

```
SELECT t.src
     , t.title
     , t.maker
     , t.partnum
     , t.price
  FROM (
         SELECT '[data]'         AS `src`
              , d1.title         AS `title`
              , d1.maker         AS `maker`
              , d1.partnum       AS `partnum`
              , d1.price         AS `price`
              , d1.partnum       AS `product`
           FROM data d1
          WHERE d1.sysn = ?

          UNION ALL

         SELECT '[cross]'
              , c2.title
              , c2.maker
              , c2.partnum
              , c2.price
              , c2.product
           FROM cross c2
           JOIN data d2
             ON d2.partnum = c2.product
          WHERE d2.sysn = ?
       )
 ORDER BY t.product DESC, t.src DESC, t.price ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, "cross" is a reserved word and you must enclose cross in backticks to use it as a table name (The backtick is next the the '1' on the keyboard on the upper left).

Comment: thank you very much guy, especialy to spencer7593. Code, that you provide works great!